# Android: Problem playing videos from internal storage

Tags: android, video, mediacontroller

I'm trying to play a video file with this code:

```
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
 mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
 mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
 Uri video = Uri.parse(path);
 videoView.setMediaController(mc);
 videoView.setVideoURI(video);
 videoView.start();
```

With videos located on the SD card it works great, but when I try to play a video from the internal storage it says it's unable to play the video.

Now, I think (but not sure) it has something to do with the fact that maybe the videos in the internal storage don't have the necessary permissions.

What do you think?

Comment: Two questions: 1. have you tried to play the same video from external and internal storage? 2. Are you talking about the same application internal storage?

Comment: @MByD 1. Yes. All the videos I try to play from internal storage don't work. The same videos work on SD card. 2. Yes.

Comment: Can you show how do you retrieve the video URI?

Comment: @MByD downloadsDir = getDir("MyTube", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);File videoFile = new File(downloadsDir, fileName); And then there is a code that downloads the data from the server and writes it to the file. I'm wondering if I set my permissions correctly.

Comment: Does parseUri returns a valid URI?

Comment: @MByD After checking with the debugger - the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE does not imply Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE.

Probably you only want only readable, but you can "or" the constants together if you do want both.